# How can I listen to Firestore data only from server?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If we want to use `.get()` method to fetch data from server only, we can use the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get(GetOptions(source: Source.server))
```

Here we used `GetOptions(source: Source.server)` to avoid reading from cache; but what if I want listen from server only, for example I have the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userss').doc('1').snapshots()
```

Or:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userss').doc('1').snapshots()listen((event) {  });
```

I tried the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userss').doc('1').snapshots()listen((event) { 
      if(!event.metadata.isFromCache) {
            print('this data from server');
            //as (!) condition it should outputs true if data was from server  
            // but as a test i turn off my wifi but it also outputs true .. How !??
      }
});
```

How can I listen from server *only*? If it's not possible, how can I at least detect if my data is from server or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way with a listener to not get any cached data, but you can check in each snapshot's metadata whether it is guaranteed to be up to date with the server by checking its [`fromCache` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#fromcache). From that link:

> True if the snapshot was created from cached data rather than guaranteed up-to-date server data. If your listener has opted into metadata updates (via `SnapshotListenOptions`) you will receive another snapshot with fromCache set to false once the client has received up-to-date data from the backend.

If the property is **false**, the data is guaranteed to be up to date from the server.

---

The alternative would be to disable disk caching.